# How to Use Keras Model to Predict Output After Unpacking the Model

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I can unpack my RNN model onto my website, but I am having trouble getting it to predict a numpy array of predictions using a list as input (contains only one string called `text` but needs to be a `list` for preprocessing from what I've gathered) and I am coming across the problem:

```
ValueError: Error when checking : expected embedding_1_input to have shape (None, 72) 
but got array with shape (1, 690)
```

Here is how I am currently preprocessing and predicting with the model:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = 5000, split=' ')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts([text])
X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([text])
X = pad_sequences(X)

prediction = loadedModel.predict(X)
print(prediction)
```

And this is how I trained my model:

```
HIDDEN_LAYER_SIZE = 195         # Details the amount of nodes in a hidden layer.
TOP_WORDS = 5000                # Most-used words in the dataset.
MAX_REVIEW_LENGTH = 500         # Char length of each text being sent in (necessary).
EMBEDDING_VECTOR_LENGTH = 128   # The specific Embedded later will have 128-length vectors to
                                # represent each word.
BATCH_SIZE = 32                 # Takes 64 sentences at a time and continually retrains RNN.
NUMBER_OF_EPOCHS = 10           # Fits RNN to more accurately guess the data's political bias.
DROPOUT = 0.2                   # Helps slow down overfitting of data (slower convergence rate)

# Define the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(TOP_WORDS, EMBEDDING_VECTOR_LENGTH, \
            input_length=X.shape[1]))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(DROPOUT))
model.add(LSTM(HIDDEN_LAYER_SIZE))
model.add(Dropout(DROPOUT))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', \
                metrics=['accuracy'])

#printModelSummary(model)

# Fit the model
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), \
            epochs=NUMBER_OF_EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

How can I fix my preprocessing code in the codebox starting with "tokenizer" to stop getting the ValueError? 
Thank you, and I can definitely provide more code or expand upon the purpose of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two problems here:

1. Set `max_len` in `pad_sequences`: it seems that all of your training sequences were padded to have length `72` so - you need to change the following line:

   ```
   X = pad_sequences(X, max_len=72)
   ```
2. Use training `Tokenizer`: this is a subtle problem - you are creating and fitting a totally new `Tokenizer` so it could be different than one which you used for training. This could cause problems - because different words could have different indexes - and this will make your model to work awful. Try to `pickle` your training `Tokenizer` and load it during deployment in order to transform sentences into data points fed to your model properly.